# PRG BestPractice Zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

i have an best practice question.

Its clear what Post/Redirect/Get does, but what will be the bestpractice to handle them?

I think there are 2 methods to handle them.

1.) We call the prg plugin at first on controller action
2.) We first validate the post data, and only redirect to the prg-response if successfull?

My problem about this is, at

1.) We enlarge the response time because of the redirect, this is by default so i think not the best solution

2.) will create an overhead by the every time validation of the form

What did you mean is the better solution aber this case?

regards

UPDATE:

What i mean is, the normal(standard) case is something like this - http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-post-redirect-get-plugin.

```
$prg = $this->prg('url');
if ($prg instanceof Response) {
    return $prg;
} elseif ($prg === false) {
    return new ViewModel(array(...));
}

$form->setData($prg);
```

This means, that theres after every form submit an redirect executes.
Now, my idea was something like this:

```
$prg  = $this->prg();
$form = $this->getFormLogin();

$data = ($prg instanceof ResponseInterface)
           ? $this->getRequest()->getPost()
           : $prg;

if (false !== $data) {
    $form->setData($data);
    if (true === $form->isValid()) {
        if ($prg instanceOf ResponseInterface) {
            return $prg;
        }

    // Make something within the loginservice or something else
}
```

The idea behind this was, to only redirect for the PRG only if the form is valid, to save response time and other things (because of bootstrapping settings etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Zend Framework is designed based on [Front-Controller](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/front_controller_pattern.htm) pattern so its essential to redirect the page when you access different resources(controller-action).

moreover when you fire redirect(URL) function from your source code it takes minimal time when you compared the time to access the same(URL) from your browser.

You could reduce the response time to considerable amount when you use classmap_autoloading.

Updated:

for an example i take login process, in the below code i implement both HTTP get and post methods in the same action() but, you can refactor this function based on HTTP methods.

LoginController.php

```
public function loginAction()
{
  //code
  if ($request->isPost()) {
     //code
    if ($isValid) {
       return $this->redirect()->toUrl('urUrl');
    }
    return $this->redirect()->toUrl('urUrl');
  }
  //code
  return $viewModel;
}
```

After refactoring above code

```
 //it used for HTTP get
    public function loginAction()
    {      
      //code
       return $viewModel;
    }

    //it used for HTTP POST
    public function loginPostAction()
    {      
        //code
        if ($notValid) {
           return $this->redirect()->toUrl('urUrl');
        }
       $viewModel->setTemplate($viewpath);
       return $viewModel;
    }
```

You need to modify your routing configuration in such a way to handle for both HTTP get and post methods. if the request is HTTP-get the controller process the loginAction() but if its HTTP-post it process the loginPostAction()

[Zend framework 2 - HTTP method Routing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-method)

**Updated:**
The purpose of plugin is to avoid the user to POST the data again to the browser. In your case you are trying to enable the option to POST their data when the form is not valid `(you are trying to change the behaviour of PRG plugin)`. if you really worried about response time don't use PRG plugin. create your custom logic inside your controller-action.

--SJ

Comment: hi, thx for your answer. What i doesnt understand in this case is the, "compared the time to access the same resource", in my case the redirect url is the same as the caller url. What i mean with point 2.) is, i exclude the redirect so long the datas are valid, the ressource calls are the same at both methods, only the redirect will be excludet, regards

Comment: @user3549136, i updated my answer. i dont understand what you actually asked me. can you clarify your question by using above loginAction()?

Comment: I've updated my Question on the top, i hope this clarify my question? The question is in this case, make it sense to handle the PRG only on valid form? regards

Comment: perfect, thank you for your examples and answers, i think it makes the scenario more clear for me :) thanks for your help

Comment: @codeninja I have a question: How do you imagine using `$prg` with standalone forms (so no framework/controller involved)? I have instantiated pluginmanager `$plugins = $v->getHelperPluginManager()` but I don't know how to proceed in order to create an instance of PRG.
The underlaying issue with my standalone form is that my data stays in the form after it has successfully submitted. I feel using PRG might help to have all inputs cleared after form submission.